# $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle Ax,x\rangle} d\lambda_n(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi^n}}{\sqrt{\det(A)}} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, matrices, change-of-variable

Let $ A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $.

Show that: $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle Ax,x\rangle } d\lambda_n(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi^n}}{\sqrt{\det(A)}}  $$

***Proof*** :

*First:* Can you tell me if my calculation is correct?

*Second:* I set a $\star_1$, $\star_2$. Can you explain me in detail $ \star_1, \star_2$? Especially $\star_2$. I know that this is change of variables theorem.

First we know: 
$A = S^t \cdot D_A \cdot S$, $S$ orthogonal and $D_A$ diagonal matrix.

We know: $1 = |\det(S)| = |det(S^t)|$.

We know that: $D_A$ = diagonal$ (\lambda_{11},...,\lambda_{nn}) $ where $\lambda_{ii} > 0$ for $ i \in $ {$1,...,n$}.

Obviously $\det(A)  = \lambda_{11} \cdots \lambda_{nn}$. So far so good.

Now:
$$-\langle Ax, x \rangle =- \langle S^ty \cdot D_A \cdot S \cdot x, x \rangle  \stackrel{(\star_1)}{=} - \langle D_A \cdot S \cdot x, S\cdot x \rangle.$$

Now:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle Ax,x\rangle} d\lambda_n(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle D_A \cdot S  \cdot x, S \cdot x \rangle } d\lambda_n(x)$$

[Now we have use transformation theorem:]
[in general $ \int f(y) dy = \int_U f(\phi(x)) \cdot | \det D\phi(x)| dx $]

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle D_A \cdot S  \cdot x, S \cdot x \rangle } d\lambda_n(x) \stackrel{(\star_2)}{=} \int_
{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle D_A \cdot y, y \rangle } \cdot |\det S|  d\lambda_n(y) = \dots $$
Rest is clear .

Comment: $d \lambda_n(x)$, $D_A, \lambda_{ii}$ ? To compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\| B x\|^2}dx$ all you need is $d (B^{-1} x) = |\det(B)|^{-1} dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-t^2}dt = \sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: $\lambda_n$ is the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$. $D_A$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries ${\lambda_{ii}}$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There are special symbols `\langle` & `\rangle` in LaTeX for angle brackets, distinct from less-than and greater-than, which render as $\langle$ & $\rangle$, respectively. Also, you can precede `det` with a backslash to transform it into a `\det` symbol, rendered as $\det$ instead of $det$.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Intuitively I know that $\star_1$ and $\star_2$ have to be true. Otherwise I would have a problem with my proof. So what exactly is my problem? I need  an explanation what exaclty does the change of variables in this case. I know that I replace $Mx$ with $y$ but what happens exactly in my integral?

Comment: What is $y$ in the first equation? Aside from that, the first starred equation is just the definition of the transpose, and the second is a standard change-of-variables result for the map $S:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm not sure what else you're looking for; you state the relevant result on the previous line.

Comment: oh! believe it or not. I think you solved my problem! Thank you. ignore the $y$  I just wanted to write the formula in general :). and thank you CiaPan for explaining the symbols.